# I'm getting segmentation fault (Core dumped)in Ubuntu Virtual terminal when running a C code, here I mentioned the following code

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm coding using Ubuntu virtual box and when I am trying to execute this following code it shows the segmentation fault (core dumped). Why this is happening? What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int n, sum = 0, c, value;

   printf("Enter the number of integers you want to add\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n",n);

   for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
       scanf("%d", &value);
       sum = sum + value;
   }
   printf("Sum of entered integers = %d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above code. It compiles and runs ok. [ideone](https://ideone.com/V226yY)

Comment: is there any problems with memory allocation like that?

Comment: You are not allocating any memory (dynamically) here. They are local variables here. so what do you mean. Can you paste how you compiled code and the error messages from the terminal here. Maybe you are doing something else

Answer (score 0):

> why this is happening?

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you show. If this code is indeed crashing, it must be because of something you *didn't* show.

If could be that your system is completely broken (does `/bin/date` work? does `/bin/sleep 1` work?), or because you are running a different binary from the one you think you are, or ...

> what should I do?

Learn how to debug. Build your program with `-g` flag, and run it under debugger (which will tell you *where* your program is crashing).

Here is a handy [starting point](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.pdf.gz).